# perl blank substitution in a string

Tags: perl

I have this two kind of strings:

```
EVASA           2144
IN ELABORAZIONE         16278
```

I need some perl script to substitute all the blanks with just one.

The output I need is:

```
EVASA 2144
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a very simple regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $line = 'EVASA           2144';

# This is the line that actually does the work
$line =~ s/\s+/ /g;

print $line, "\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be that you spend some time reading the [Regular Expression tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) that is distributed with every modern version of Perl.

Comment: I agree with you, but sometime I love the human various interpretation of a solution. It make me understand more than reading a book! I'm already reading the book you suggested to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = "hello    \t world";
$a =~ s/\s+/ /;
print $a;
```

if you may have multiple places in the string where you want the substitution to take place, use

```
$a = "hello    \t world    hi";
$a =~ s/\s+/ /g;
print $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `tr`operator with the `s` Option, this can do more things for you (transforming characters), probably faster than the regexp approach

```
$a =~ tr/ \t/ /s;
```

Explanation can be found in the `perlop` manpage:

```
perldoc perlop
```